# Filter a pandas document using row and column keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv document that looks like the following one:

```
_id_ name score_1 score_2 score_3
5254454 John 10 8 9
5435454 Chris 8 6 7
1233123 John 5 5 6
65566565 Jim nan nan nan
... ... ... ...
```

Most of the rows do not have a value for the score_1 column, so I would like to access them and fill a grade.

So, I would like to filter the score_1 of a specific person using his `id` or `name`. So if the dataframe name is `df` I am trying to do something like that:

```
df.loc[df['_id_']==int(id1)] # which actually filters a row
```

Then, I would like to filter this row with the key of score_1 and add a value and in the end, save the updated dataframe to CSV. How can I do that?

I have tried to do sth like that but it failed:

```
df.loc[df['_id_']==int(id1)][df['score_1']] = 10
```

Comment: Do you have the calues you want to update with?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do sth like df.loc[df['_id_']==int(id1)][df['score_1']] = 10 for instance. But apparently it does not work.

Comment: Use `df.loc[df['id']==int(id1), "score_1"] = 10`

Comment: How many values do you have. eg do you have another table with id, value eg in your case `id1, 10` another id with its replacement value etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['_id_']==int(id1), 'score_1'] = 10
```